# How do I use an HIMAGELIST (from SetupDiGetClassImageList) as a .NET ImageList?

Tags: .net, imagelist

I've got an `HIMAGELIST` (from `SetupDiGetClassImageList`) and I'd like to use it with a Windows Forms `ListView`, which needs an `ImageList`. There's no `ImageList.FromHandle`.

How do I use my `HIMAGELIST` as an `ImageList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Not possible](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/531092-get-class-imagelist) but you can use [SetupDiLoadClassIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms792961.aspx) instead

Comment: Actually, it looks like it is possible, by copying the icons (ImageList_GetIcon) from one to the other. I couldn't get the colour depth and mask working in the half an hour I had...

Comment: You ask how to (re)use the handle, not how to copy the data from one to the other.

Comment: Reading it again, I guess I did ask that. What I meant was: I've got an HIMAGELIST; how do I get an ImageList with the same images in it? Hey ho. Moving on.